# No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am writing a simple test case where i am opening a chrome browser with the url using robot framework with python and selenium2library

I HAVE TRIED ALL THE WAYS TO MAKE IT DONE ,LIKE INSTALLING AND UNINSTALLING THE PYTHON ETC

HERE IS THE ERROR

```
No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
=============================================================================
```

Comment: Are you importing a library that includes that keyword, or have you defined that keyword yourself? If you are importing, do you get import errors? Without seeing a [mcve] it's impossible for us to do anything other than guess. Please [edit] your question to include the smallest possible robot test that gives this error.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. You can [edit] your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 7):

You need to include a line in your ***Settings*** section that says

```
Library | SeleniumLibrary
```

and you might also need to run

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Good luck!

Comment: C:\Users\PC\IdeaProjects\untitled\Suite>pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleliumlibrary
Collecting robotframework-seleliumlibrary
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-seleliumlibrary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework-seleliumlibrary

Comment: I am using the following version:Package                         Version
------------------------------- -------
pip                             19.1.1
robotframework                  3.1.2
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  3.3.1
selenium                        3.141.0
setuptools                      41.0.1
urllib3                         1.25.3

Comment: OK, so you have seleniumlibrary installed; do you have the Library line at the top?

Comment: I think you should do as Bryan Oakley suggests above and post (at least some of) your code.

Answer (score 4):

This type of error message may have several reasons :
1- The number of spacing between keywords and the variable;
2- Lack of loading of the test library;
3- ...

With robot framework the spacing is at least size 4. For exemple
Library    SeleniumLibrary

Here's a simple test case to open the chrome browser and enter the url https://google.fr :

Style 1 :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser     https://google.fr    chrome
```

**Style 2 :**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN URL}      https://google.fr
${BROWSER}        Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser     ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask them. Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

*(I know it's been some time but if it can help others...)*

Following that error message, you probably had an issue with the browser driver.

I struggled to find the "PATH" where geckodriver (for Firefox) should be, and a colleague helped me so I share ; hope it could help someone who, like me, would spend hours on stackoverflow and such:

```
echo $PATH
```

(I'm on macos so it should also work for Linux, not sure for Windows)

Then, a simple `open /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` (or any other path the previous line gave you), and copy the geckodriver exe there :)

Answer (score 1):

In my guess that you don't install selenium library, in above case you may mispelled it to *robotframework-seleliumlibrary* instead of **robotframework-seleniumlibrary**.
Follow the pip install instructment above, and have a try again~
(May I should comment at the corresponding reply, but it is low for my reputation = - =)

Comment: Your answer is good. Why you should care about reputation if it help others ?

Comment: Yeah, that is not need. Thank you, that is something I suffered ever.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your geckodriver should be added to the PATH environment variable.
Add geckodriver for firefox or similar files in python/Scripts folder and add Scripts folder to environment variable. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Varify Basic search Functionality for google :: This test case ver... | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Maximize Window' found.

Maximize Window will not work in robot framework.

The code is -

```
Maximize Browser Window
```